# Problem with authentication on subsites (internal/external approach)

Tags: authentication, domain, credentials

This our current situation

1 main-site foo.org and 2 subsites foo.org/FR and foo.org/EN (French and English)
When you'll browse to foo.org, you're redirected directly to foo.org/FR/default.aspx
And this is the moment where we're facing the following problem:

- SharePoint keeps asking for credentials for the administrator. (while using http://foo.org)
- When I add www it just logs me in as an Administrator. (http://www.foo.org)

-> This may be caused by the domain controller (which is outsourced here at work, and they're not willing to change permissions/settings)

-> adding the website to the trusted websites isn't a solution either

-> changing logon activities to a custom level also didn't work.

When I navigate to 'http://foo.org/FR/shared pages/foopage.aspx', SP asks for credentials. When I navigate to 'http://www.foo.org/FR/shared pages/foopage.aspx', SP just logs me in as an administrator, which is bad of course.

If I navigate towards to the http://foo.org/EN it redirects me to the /EN/default.aspx without asking for credentials, AND not logged in as an administrator (just as a visitor).

The problem is situated in the /FR subsite I think. When I check the masterpages of /EN and /FR, the only difference is at the point where you're able to set up the visibility of 'view all site content': (see PermissionString)

```
FR/master.page
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="ViewPageForms">
<div class="ms-quicklaunchheader"><SharePoint:SPLinkButton id="idNavLinkViewAll" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx" Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent%>" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/></div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>



EN/master.page
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageLists">
<div class="ms-quicklaunchheader"><SharePoint:SPLinkButton id="idNavLinkViewAll" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"Text="%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent%>" AccessKey="%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/></div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

When using Fiddler, it says it needs authentication at the point where the /FR/Default.aspx is loaded. The only difference between the /EN/Default.aspx and /FR/Default.aspx is:

```
FR/Default.aspx
<META NAME=”ROBOTS” CONTENT=”NOHTMLINDEX”/>
<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”/FR/_styles/core.css”/>

EN/Default.aspx
<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”/_layouts/1036/styles/core.css?rev=qaEkY9lls4D7o5XsuDYM1g%3D%3D”/>
```

Comment: Can you share the managed paths settings as well ?

Comment: Ben, without the managed path it will be rather difficult to identify the root cause. I have seen in more than a few occasions where multilingual sites behaved erratically when the fix was applied at the managed paths level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem(s) solved:

- There was no anonymous access to my Calendar
- The maintenance-settings for the Calendar-webpart weren't set wright

The only way to access this webpart maintenance page is by adding '/default.aspx?contents=1'
At this page you should check the following:

- Make sure your webpart is 'open at page' => Yes and 'Personalised' => No

Excuse me for wrong translations but I'm using SharePoint in French.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that it logs you in as admin instead - are you saying you should be allowed access anonymously or authenticated but just a lower priv account?

I recently had an issue where we got challenged at root but okay if we went in direct at a lower level URL. Turned out I needed to switch anonymous access at the site collection AND web app level on then off again to get something internally synced up and make it start working.

Comment: The web application level anonymous setting is done at the athentication provider setting in central admin. Manage Web Apps -> select an app, click authentication providers. Check/uncheck the anonymous access box. This makes web.config changes so be careful. The site collection level is under site settings -> site permissions -> Anonymous Access button in the ribbon, you will only see this button if you have anonymous set at web app level as described earlier.

Comment: We have set up a revision by a SharePoint specialist, the answer will follow later on.